# Java JSON serialization and JSONObject

Tags: java, json, org.json

I tried this:

```
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import org.apache.commons.lang.Validate;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.Media;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public static class MyJSON implements Serializable {
    private final String name = "myname";

    // **Why don't I get this field serialized in the response?**
    private final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    public MyJSON() {
        try {
            jsonObject.put("mykey", "myvalue");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public JSONObject getJsonObject() { return jsonObject; }

}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get all entities", notes = "get all entities", response = Response.class)
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK status"),

public Response getList() {

    return Response.ok(new MyJSON(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

the response I get:

```
{
  "name": "myname"
}
```

as you see I get only the `name` field of `MyJSON` without the `jsonObject` field.

**any ideas how can I get the `jsonObject` fields also serialized?**

UPDATE:

after reading Thomas comment I tried using a map:

```
public static class MyJSON implements Serializable {
    private final String name = "myname";
    private final Map somefield = new HashMap();

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public Map getSomefield() { return somefield; }

    public void addOther(String key, String value) {
        somefield.put(key, value);
    }

}

        MyJSON myJSON = new MyJSON();
        myJSON.addOther("mhykey", "myvalue");
        return Response.ok(myJSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

Now I get again:

```
{
  "name": "myname" // where is the other field? (the map)
}
```

I wonder again why doesn't it serializes it? please note I can't use specific objects because the json can vary at one scenario certain fields at another scenario other fields, I can't create a new class for each such case.

Comment: Did you try using a plain `Map<String, Object>` instead of `JSONObject`? Since the pojo is serialized to json the mapper might have problems when encountering `JSONObject`s directly. Besides that it might be better to use specific objects anyways, i.e. instead of a map you could provide a nested pojo that has the `mykey` field.

Comment: How would you like it to be serialized?

Comment: @Thomas updated question (see UPDATE) according to your suggestion.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `{ "name": "value", "mykey": "myvalue" }`

Comment: I see you have the Gson tag, however you are not using it. I'm going to remove that tag.

Comment: @cricket_007 JAX-RS might be using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is how you want the class to be serialized

```
{
    "name": "value",
    "mykey": "myvalue"
}
```

Then this is how your object should look like

```
class Data { 
    String name, String mykey;

    // getters, setters...
}
```

Alternatively, when @Thomas said, a HashMap, he did not mean "nest" a HashMap into the Object, he literally meant use a HashMap, though, not all JSON libraries support that constructor.

```
HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
data.put("name", "value");
data.put("mykey", "myvalue");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
String jsonString = json.toString();
```

Another thing you could do is just treat your object as a JSONObject itself.

```
class Data extends JSONObject {

    public Data() { }

}
```

```
Data d = new Data();
d.put("name", "value");
```

Though, that seems silly.